# Response is coming different in different android apps

Tags: android, android-asynctask, response

when i type  URl  in browser i get correct response

```
 [{"responseCode":0},{"rewardPoints":-15000,"receipt":"20160909110957"}]   ,
```

but when i am trying to get response through android i get response as

```
[{"responseCode":111}]   ,
```

i am trying to get response like this

```
class Transid extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog  pdia;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(PopupActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdia.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            String jsonString = new String();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            jsonString = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonString);
            JSONArray parentarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            JSONObject finalobject = parentarray.getJSONObject(1);
            transactionid = finalobject.getString("receipt");

            setTransactionid(transactionid);
            return ("" + transactionid);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        return transactionid;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
   }
 }
```

i use same code in different app and it is working fine

Why am i getting different response in this app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the working code below.It is tested and working correctly

```
 @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
         URL url;
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
         try {
             url=new URL("url?userId=4&points=15000&ipaddress=yourip");
             urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
             urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
             urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
             urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
             urlConnection.connect();

             int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

             if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                 String  server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
              Log.v("Yorclass.this.getClass().getName()",server_response);
             }

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }


 public  String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

The output is

> [{"responseCode":0},{"rewardPoints":-15000,"receipt":"20160909110957"}]

Comment: Please remove the url from the answer, i cant edit it,else i may have to delete question,it will cost you 25 rep.

Comment: You should probably explain what was wrong with the original code and how this answer fixes it.